# Will redeploying a project to the SSISDB invalidate current jobs

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I’ve been given 2 dtsx packages to replace 2 in production. This is for a SQL 2012 server with the packages deployed in the project model. The only way I see to do the update is to export the project, replace the existing packages with the revised versions, then redeploy the project to the same “path” in the server.  My question is will the current SQL Agent jobs, calling individual packages, continue to work or are there guid issues or anything else that would cause the jobs to fail?